# web-scraping multiprocessing doesn't work

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use web-scraping on large number of urls and I apply the multiprocessing to speed up but don't know why it cannot speed up at all. Here is part of my code:

```
def scrape(url,output_path):
    page = urlopen(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    item_text = soup.select('#scatter6001 script')[0].text
    table = soup.find_all('table',{'class':'noborder dark'})
    df1 = pd.read_html(str(table),header = 0)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1[0])
    ...
# function for scraping the data from url

rootPath = '...' 
urlp1 = "https://www.proteinatlas.org/"

try:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(rootPath + "cancer_list1_2(1).csv", header=0);
except Exception as e:
    print("File " + f + " doesn't exist")
    print(str(e))
    sys.exit()

cancer_list = df1.as_matrix().tolist()

URLs = []
for cancer in cancer_list:

    urlp2 = "/pathology/tissue/" + cancer[1]
    f = cancer[0]
    
    try:
        df1 = pd.read_csv(rootPath + f + ".csv", header=0);
    except Exception as e:
        print("File " + f + " doesn't exist")
        print(str(e))
        sys.exit()
    ...
# list of URLs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)
    records = p.map(scrape(url,output_path))

    p.terminate()
    p.join()
```

Not sure how to speed up the web-scraping using multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually using multiprocessing. You're running the `scrape` function once and passing the result as an argument to `p.map()`. Instead, you need to pass a callable taking one argument, for example:

```
func = lambda url: scrape(url, output_path)
p.map(func, list_of_urls)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but after I modifying the code it still cannot speed up. `if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)
    func = lambda url: scrap(url, output_path)
    p.map(func, URLs)

    p.terminate()
    p.join()`

Comment: Excuse me but I'm quite new to python and multiprocessing.

Comment: Have you used multiprocessing successfully on test code?

Comment: Still cannot. shows the error `pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x00000192732AAF28>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed`